# What is the reason for this segmentation fault in this Linked List program?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

This program always gives me a Segmentation Fault when I add the last node, what could be the possible reason. it only comes while adding the last node, I have commented the line in which I get the segmentation fault.
I'm new to programming.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};


struct node *createNode(int val){
        struct node *ret=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        ret->data=val;
        ret->next=NULL;
        return ret;
}


struct node *addNode(struct node *ll,int val){
        //Gives error here for the last node, it creates the node succesfull but this step give segmentation fault
        struct node *new_node=createNode(val);
        new_node->next=ll;
        return new_node;
}

void printList(struct node *ll){
        printf("printing list");
        struct node *temp=ll;
        while(temp->next){
                printf("%d ->",temp->data);
                temp=temp->next;
        }
}

int main(){
        struct node *head;
        head=addNode(head,3);
        head=addNode(head,5);
        head=addNode(head,1);
        head=addNode(head,9);
        printList(head);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running it through a debugger? If not, do it and observe the value of all variables in scope, looking for anything suspect.

Comment: You might like to have a read here: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: I'd expected the code to crash in here: `printList()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 struct node *head;
```

`head` is uninitialized so using uninitialized variables leads to undefined behavior. Initialize your `head` to `NULL` before adding nodes.

```
 struct node *head = NULL;
```

[DO NOT CAST MALLOC AND FAMILY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 1):

Assign  `NULL` to the head.

```
 struct node * head=NULL;
```

because in addnode you are doing like this,

```
 new_node->next=ll;
```

Then while printing the node make the condition like this,

```
while(node){
...
}
```

If you use the `node>next` you will loss the last value in the linked list.

[Don't cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) the malloc and family.

Answer (score 0):

you are facing this problem because when you are adding the new node in the link list you are adding this node as a start of the linklist.

Initially:

```
struct node* head; //This is not NULL.Big mistake by you.But this is not the only problem.
```

The segmentation fault is there because you are trying to access the invalid memory location in `printList()`, as the last node pointer( which was firstly declared by you as `head`) is not pointing to any valid memory location.Try commenting the call to `printList()` you will see that bug goes.But this is not the solution you are looking for, even if you initialize the head to `NULL` you will face the problem where last node will not get printed.for this use:-

```
while(temp)
```

in `printList()`.